# Getting an error when creating a search page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a search page that searches through the model courses. Courses has a "name" column that lists the names of courses. I created a search controller and this is what I have on my search controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
def search  
    if params[:search].blank?  
      redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Empty field!") and return  
    else  
      @parameter = params[:search].downcase  
      @results = Courses.all.where("lower(name) LIKE :search", search: @parameter)  
    end  
  end
   def show 
 render 'search'
end
end
```

I have under views/search a  search.html.erb page. On this page I have

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get",   
class: 'navbar-form navbar-left') do %>  
<div class="input-group">  
<%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>  
<div class="input-group-btn">  
  <%= button_tag "", :class => 'btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-search',:name => nil%>  
 </div>  
 </div>  
 <% end %>

<h3>Search Result</h3>  

<% @results.each do |result| %>  
    <%= result.name %><br>  
<% end %>
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run my rails server and click on search and I am not sure why @results is null. Thanks for the help!

```
11: <h3>Search Result</h3>  
12: 
13:     <% @results.each do |result| %>  
14:         <%= result.name %><br>  
15:     <% end %>
```

Comment: You need to declare @results in case `params[:search].blank?` is true. Currently is returning a NoMethodError because accessing an undeclared instance variable only returns nil, and nil instances don't implement `each`.

Answer (score 0):

When the form provided in `app/views/search/search.html.erb` is submitted, the request is sent to `show` action by default. But the `show` action just renders the search view, no `@results` is assigned and the error occurs.

The `search` action seems unnecessary and you should use the `show` action instead. For example, rename `app/views/search/search.html.erb` to `app/views/search/show.html.erb` and move the `search` code to `show` action as below:

app/controllers/search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def show 
    if params[:search].blank?  
      redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Empty field!")  
    else  
      @parameter = params[:search].downcase  
      @results = Courses.all.where("lower(name) LIKE :search", search: @parameter)  
    end
  end
end
```